# Problems Rendering on Safari Only

Tags: css, macos, safari

I'm a Windows user and all browsers I have load the page right. I've been told from a mac user that top header overlaps the logo when you visit an inner page (not when on the home page).
http://www.wearcozy.com/product-category/jewelry/necklaces/diamond-necklaces/

Since I don't have Safari it makes it much harder for me to troubleshoot.

Can anybody using Mac help me out to figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Problems found:

`#headertext .topicon` has **height** of `55px`, which is higher than the black bar of 25px

`#topminicart` has **height** of `55px`, which is higher than the black bar of 25px

`#topminicart` has **margin-top** of `-43px !important` (!!!)

`.sn li` has **height** of `30px`, which is higher than the black bar of 25px

Comment: it's still a misery to me how it renders it right on the homepage, but not inner pages.